# target encoding train and test data set with many categorical columns

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data, data-processing

I am trying to prepare a training dataset which contains many categorical columns with high cardinality to train a machine learning model. Therefore, I want to target encoding them so that I convert the categorical columns into numerical columns. Label encoding is not suitable because the categorical features are not ordinal

My train dataset looks like this where I have only taken 4 columns out of 20 columns

| target | cat_col1 | cat_col2 | cat_col3 | cat_col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | city1 | james | 25-55 | abc |
| 20 | city2 | adam | 30-40 | bcc |
| 15 | city1 | charles | 30-40 | bcc |

I want to write an efficient code to target encode all the categorical columns without individually having to do each column.

The resulting training dataframe should look like

| target | cat_col1 | cat_col2 | cat_col3 | cat_col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 15 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 20 | 20 | 20 | 17 | 17 |
| 15 | 15 | 15 | 17 | 17 |

I can get the above output by writing code for each column but since I have 20 categorical, this does not seem efficient.

```
encoder = TargetEncoder()
train['cat_col1'] = encoder.fit_transform(train['cat_col1'], train['target'])
train['cat_col2'] = encoder.fit_transform(train['cat_col2'], train['target'])
train['cat_col3'] = encoder.fit_transform(train['cat_col3'], train['target'])
train['cat_col4'] = encoder.fit_transform(train['cat_col4'], train['target'])
```

In addition, I would like to take the target encoded values of the train dataframe and replace all the categories in the test dataframe with the train target encoded values.

Comment: Why don't you use pd.get_dummies()?

Comment: Hey. because I don't want to blow up the number of columns because each column has large number of categorical values (High cardinality)

Comment: But then the alternative is label encoding and you don't want that.

Comment: Yes because the categorical features in the column are not ordinal

Comment: Ah, so you want something that's not doing one-hot encoding or label encoding. 
What's the issue with blowing up your columns? Your ML algorithm shouldn't mind.

Comment: My dataset is also very large, blowing it up is computationally very expensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `category_encoders` implementation, it should accept several columns just fine, at least for the recent versions:

```
cat_cols = ['cat_col1', 'cat_col2', 'cat_col3', 'cat_col4']

train[cat_cols] = encoder.fit_transform(train[cat_cols], train['target'])
test[cat_cols] = encoder.transform(test[cat_cols])
```

Alternatively, you could use a loop:

```
for column in cat_cols:
    encoder = TargetEncoder()
    train[column] = encoder.fit_transform(train[column], train['target'])
    test[column] = encoder.transform(test[column])
```